# Modify maximum entropy problem to fix specific Lagrange multiplier

Tags: analysis, optimization, convex-optimization, lagrange-multiplier

I have an optimization problem of the form

$\min_p -H(p) \text{ s.t. } \sum_{x \in \mathcal{X}} p(x)=1 \text{ and } g_i(p)=c_i \text{ for } i=1, \dots, m$

where $p \in [0,1]^{|\mathcal{X}|} $ is a discrete probability distribution over a set $\mathcal{X}$.

From e.g. Chapter 3 of [Wainwright/Jordan 2008](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ewainwrig/Papers/WaiJor08_FTML.pdf), I know that the solution to the above optimization problem is of the form

$p(x) = \exp\left(\lambda_0 + \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i g_i(x) \right)$.

for some constants $\lambda_i \in \mathbb{R}$ (the Lagrange multipliers).

In the solution $p(x)$ above I want one of the coefficients $\lambda_i$ to have a fixed value, say for example I want to fix $\lambda_1=5$. Is there a way to enforce a constraint like $\lambda_1=5$ in the original maximum entropy problem?

Comment: You do not force the multipliers to a specific value, their value should be found so that you actually solve the optimization problem. Why would you like to do that in the first place?

Comment: For some more context, if it helps:
(1) My (convex) optimization problem is a maximum entropy problem (ie f(x) = -H(x)) 

(2) I know the solution has the form f(x) ~ exp(\sum_i lambda_i g_i(x) ).

(3) For my specific use-case, I want one of the coefficients lambda_1 to be fixed to a specific value.

Comment: You will have to add details in your post to clarify what you are trying to do, and also why you want to do that. It is possible that you are going completely in the wrong direction.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. What do you think now @KBS ?

Comment: No, you cannot do that (i.e. set your Lagrange multipliers to a specific value). This is not how this works. What you can do is to play around with your optimization problem so that the multipliers $\lambda_i$ take some specific value. This may not be very easy. Do you have the closed-form expression of the multipliers in the general case?

Comment: Sorry I should not call them Lagrange multipliers. But yes that is what I want to do. Unfortunately I do not have a closed-form  expression for the multipliers $\lambda_i$. However one idea which I will try is to take the dual of the max entropy optimization problem, add the constraint $\lambda_1=5$, and then take the dual of that problem. Assuming I can compute these dual problems this might give me a way to enforce the constraint $\lambda_1=5$.